# CORS error when redirecting to Stripe checkout

Tags: node.js, angular, post, get, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a basic Angular app where you can choose from 3 different plans and check out with Stripe.

What happens now is that when one of the buttons is pressed, nothing happens and I get 3 errors in the console which I don't really understand.

I want the 3 buttons to redirect the user to the checkout page with the right priceId.

otp-plans.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { StripeService } from 'ngx-stripe';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-otp-plans',
  templateUrl: './otp-plans.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./otp-plans.component.css']
})
export class OtpPlansComponent {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private stripeService: StripeService
  ) { }

  products = [
    {
      name: 'Basic',
      price: 30.99,
      priceId: 'price_1N1IFtG68nNSlGgfGtVYENCJ',
      features: [
        '1 user',
        '10 GB of storage',
        'Help center access',
        'Email support',
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Premium',
      price: 129.99,
      priceId: 'price_1N1IIhG68nNSlGgf6URNg1iR',
      features: [
        '10 users',
        '100 GB of storage',
        'Help center access',
        'Email support',
        'Phone support',
        'SSO via Google'
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Ultimate',
      price: 579.99,
      priceId: 'price_1N1IJjG68nNSlGgfeY6tx2nk',
      features: [
        'Unlimited users',
        'unlimited storage',
        'Help center access',
        'Email support',
        'Phone support',
        'Custom branding',
        'Knowledge base',
        'SSO via Google',
      ],
    },
  ];

  checkout(priceId: string) {
    // Check the server.js tab to see an example implementation
    this.http.post('/create-checkout-session', { priceId })
      .pipe(
        switchMap((session: any) => {
          return this.stripeService.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id })
        })
      )
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result.error) {
          alert(result.error.message);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

otp-plans.component.html

```html
<div id="otp-plans-container">
    <header>
        <h2>One-time-payment plans</h2>
        <p>Pay once, for lifetime use</p>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="plan">
            <div class="plan-header">
                <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>
                <p>€{{ product.price }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="plan-body">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let feature of product.features" class="plan-included">{{ feature }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="plan-footer">
                <button (click)="checkout(product.priceId)">Buy Now</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

server.js

```js
const stripe = require('stripe')('#Mykey#');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

const PORT = 8080
const YOUR_DOMAIN = `http://localhost:${PORT}`;

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors({origin: ["http://localhost:8080", "https://checkout.stripe.com"],}));
app.use(express.static('dist/payment-system'));

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/index.html');
});

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
    const { priceId } = req.body;

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
        {
        price: priceId,
        quantity: 1,
        },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
    });
    res.redirect(303, session.url);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Running on port ${PORT}`));
```

---

I can start my node.js server but when I click one of the buttons I get the following 3 errors:

```
Acess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1eCLDbYvJWjLbbPdwPeRzoSBulRVhuKGNUISFzB5bt2HJFyACEyoSdklw#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0SzRMPWNCMz1rS1ZpQmJjaE5RZEwwYkh3RF9XSWpDcXZtdk41YTcxXEFoYn9RbUN1dEYyaGRwSU1cY0pralJtPE5fTnxXPDdjXXU2dDxMZDF3M0xrbzFBNTVzXE8xMGxuVicpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/create-checkout-session') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
GET https://chps://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1eCLDbYvJWjLbbPdwPeRzoSBulRVhuKGNUISFzB5bt2HJFyACEyoSdklw net::ERR_FAILED
```

```
ROR iC{headers: Tn, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: '/create-checkout-session', ok: false, …}

error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers: Tn {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for /create-checkout-session: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse" 
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "/create-checkout-session"
[[Prototype]]: Id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently making a JS HTTP POST request to your server from your client which expects a response. But, on your server you are redirecting the client to the Checkout Session URL. Since the client never gets a response from the server, and instead the client is attempted to be redirected to a different origin, you encounter the CORS error.

To fix this you can either pass the Checkout Session ID back to your client and use it with `redirectToCheckout` (like your code is currently trying to do though doesn't actually do since you use `res.redirect(303, session.url);` on your server). Or, you can use a form submit from your HTML code to call your server instead of a JS HTTP POST request -- form submits do not expect a response like the HTTP POST request does so it allows you to redirect right from your server.

Comment: This is the new error I get: ERROR IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.

Don't I pass the lineItems in the post request in server.js?

Comment: That means you aren't properly passing the Session ID to `redirectToCheckout()` (https://stripe.com/docs/js/deprecated/redirect_to_checkout#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-sessionId) in your client-side code so you want to log out what your server is passing back to your client and ensure it is the ID as expected.

Comment: I eventually made it work, I used the method with a form that performs a post request and added a hidden field with the product's price id so it get's included in the request body and passed to the server. Thanks a lot for the help my man!